# Why is the [Authorize] attribute not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 web site, and when the user logs in, I do the following...

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(customer.GetSalutation, rememberMe);
```

I have a CustomerController, that is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute...

```
[Authorize]
public class CustomerController : Controller {
  public ActionResult Ferret() {
    return View();
  }
}
```

...but this seems to be ignored. If I try to access /Customer/Ferret, it allows is quite happily.

I tried adding [Authorize] to the controller method as well, but that didn't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you logged into the app? If so, log out and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update - found the problem!**

I realised that the situation isn't quite as I described. If I log out and try and access /Customer/Ferret, I get sent to the log-in page as expected.

I have a static class LoggedInUser, which contains a property called Me, which holds info about the logged in user.

The problem comes when I upload a new version of the site (which is happening quite a lot at the moment, as we are actively developing and rolling out new versions several times a day). If someone is logged in, and I update the site, the site gets recompiled. Their auth cookie doesn't get removed, as they didn't log out, but when they try to access the page, the auth info is not there, so I get a null reference exception on the LoggedInuser class.

I added the following to Global.asax and it fixed the problem...

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
  if (LoggedInUser.Me == null || LoggedInUser.Me.LgID == 0) {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  }
}
```

That did the trick. If they try to access a page after a recompile, LoggedInUser.Me will be null (or LgID will be zero) and they will be logged out, which will send them to the log-in page.

Don't know if this will help anyone, but I'm posting it in case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you remove the set cookie on user signout. If it is still there, it will consider the user to be logged in and by pass the authorize.

Call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` on you signout event.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. I am removing the cookie, and if I log out normally, I can't get to the page. I just realised that the problem arises if I upload a new version of the site (or start a new debug session in VS), which causes the site to be recompiled. The cookie wasn't removed, as the user didn't log out, but I can still access the authorised page. Any ideas how to get round this? I'll update the question to clarify this. Thanks

Comment: Whilst updating the question, I worked out how to fix it. Thanks anyway